# How to prove this $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}H_{k}\equiv 1\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p\ge 5$ prime number,show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}H_{k}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
where $H_{k}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{k}$.

it is well-known that $$H_{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p$$,but I can't use this result to solve my problem

Comment: I'm afraid this sum is not integer. Maybe you meant the numerator of expression?

Comment: this is $\pmod p$, such $\dfrac{a}{b}\pmod p \equiv \dfrac{a\pmod p}{b\pmod p}$

Comment: Does anyone have an idea, why anyone would make the restriction $p \geq 5$? Both the statement and the proof are also correct for $p=2,3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether I understood definition of congruence for rationals, so please point it out if you know I did.

Every summand $\frac 1 i$ is included in the sum exactly $p-i$ times, as it appears once in every $H_k$ for $k \geq i$. Therefore

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} H_k \equiv_p \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{p-k}{k} \equiv_p \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} -k\cdot k^{-1} \equiv_p \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} -1 \cdot (1) \equiv_p -(p-1) \equiv_p 1
$$

Comment: This looks good. A rational number $\frac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}$ can be identified with $rt$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, given that $p$ does not divide $s$, where $t$ is the inverse of $s$ modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete example take $p = 7$
Think of this as this sum of the elements in this array:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{6} \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{5}&0 \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} &0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &0&0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0&0&0&0  \\
 1 & 0&0&0&0&0  \\
\end{array}
$$

Since $p-k \equiv -k \mod p$, we can rewrite this array:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{1} \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{2}&0 \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} &0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &0&0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0&0&0&0  \\
 1 & 0&0&0&0&0  \\
\end{array}
$$
Cancelling out terms in rows we get that the sum is the equal to the sum of elements in 
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0&0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 &0 &0&0 \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &0 &0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &0&0&0  \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0&0&0&0  \\
 1 & 0&0&0&0&0  \\
\end{array}
$$

This is (all mod $p$ of course) 
$$ (p-2)/1 + (p-4)/2 + (p-6)/3 +\cdots +(1)/(\frac{p-1}{2}) = \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (p-2*k)/k$$
Write out this sum in terms of an $H_k$ term and one other and your answer falls out easily.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to enedil's answer (with the same disclaimer), but more explicitly:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} H_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \dfrac{p-k}{k}$

$= p\left(H_{p-1}-1\right) +1$

$\equiv 1 \mod p$